# how to read array of json objects from json file in python

Tags: python, json

i have a json file called `example.json`, containing the following content

```
[{
 "product/productId" : "XXX",
  "product/title" : "14k Yellow Gold Butterfly Pendant, 16 ",
  "product/price" : "unknown",
  "review/userId" : "XXX",
  "review/profileName" : "Disappointed Sony customer",
  "review/helpfulness" : "1/1",
  "review/score" : "4.0",
  "review/time" : "1178150400",
  "review/summary" : "pretty necklace",
  "review/text" : "It is a nice made necklace, and the butterfly pendant looks beautiful. I love it.",
 "numOfPositive" : "2",
 "numOfNegative" : "0"
},
{ "product/productId" : "XXXX",
  "product/title" : "14k Yellow Gold Butterfly Pendant, 16 ",
  "product/price" : "unknown",
  "review/userId" : "TTT",
  "review/profileName" : "A. Thorpe  Amazon lover ",
  "review/helpfulness" : "1/1",
  "review/score" : "4.0",
  "review/time" : "1175990400",
  "review/summary" : "pretty necklace",
  "review/text" : "I bought this necklace on a whim; I love butterflies and it looked so dainty anadfasdfasdfd sweet. It was actually a little more weighty than I expected, although it's not a solid piece. The chain is shiny and nicer than I expected.",
 "numOfPositive" : "4",
 "numOfNegative" : "0"
}]
```

meaning - the file contains allot of documents separated by ",".
how can i read each json-document separatly and handle it (send it to a rest api) in python?
p.s. 
the original file is can have a large size of few GB

Comment: That is not valid JSON. It contais *two* objects without an outer array. But that seems to be your problem. Who produced this "JSON" file?

Comment: Wait! Does your input contain the `[]` pair or not? Is your question about *splitting* the input?

Comment: it does contain the [] pair. how do i split each object in the array?

Comment: If the input is *one* flle of several GB size, use an external tool like `sed`  to split the input into many small files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open the file with any text editor.  Add a `[` at the very beginning of the file, and a `]` at the very end.  This will transform the data you have into an actual valid JSON array.

Then use the [json module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to work with it.

```
import json
arr = json.loads("example.json")
# Do nifty stuff with resulting array.
```

Comment: the loadS method is for strings, so json.loads("example.json") will attempt to parse "example.json", the string, as if it were json rather than a file name with json in it.

Comment: Agree with @ChrisChiasson. It should be `arr = json.load("example.json")`.

Comment: you can not pass a string into `json.load(..)`, the first parameter it expects is a file object. The correct way would be
`
with open("example.json", "r") as f:
  arr = json.load(f)
`